# How to install AppArmor on alpine

Tags: alpine-linux, apparmor

I have a container with alpine image (`docker:dind`) and I want to install ApparMor inside it to see how it works before I put it on the host.

I found [ApparMor package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/apparmor) in alpine repostiroy but I don't understand how to install it.

How can I install it and start using it?

**EDIT:**
On Ubuntu I succeeded with:
`apt-get update && apt-get install apparmor-utils`

But when I tried on alpine with:
`apk update && apk add apparmor-utils`
It failed:

```
/ # apk update && apk add apparmor-utils
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.8.2-19-g151c2021d6 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main]
v3.8.2-18-gd7f33f856a [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community]
OK: 9546 distinct packages available
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  apparmor-utils (missing):
    required by: world[apparmor-utils]
```

Comment: Alpine has its own repository, and often names can be a bit different: [pkgs.alpinelinux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/apparmor). So looks like`apk add apparmor` should do the trick. Side note: looks like this is in the test repository. Most likely you need to add that to `/etc/apk/repositories`. `sudo echo 'http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing' >> /etc/apk/repositories && sudo apk update && sudo info apparmor`

Comment: Good practice for test repositories is `pinning`, check out the documentation [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) and search for _Repository pinning_. In this case you won't just upgrade packages that you rather not want from testing. So be aware that I can screw up your installation based on my previous comment where I just echo the repository in without using _pinning_.

Comment: @rowan I am running the alpine inside a container so I don't care if something will happen. I tried your first suggestion and it failed on `info apparmor`: `sh: appramor: not found`

Comment: Did you add the repository? I just tested it, and it worked.

Comment: It seems to be installed but the command ` info apparmor` is not working.  I noticed I have a new command `apparmor_parser`. Does it mean that it installed? I thought I need to have a binary named `apparmor`.

Answer (score 1):

The package `apparmor` isn't available in the `main` repository. It can be installed from the [`testing`](http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/) repository, `edge` branch :

Add the following line to your `/etc/apk/repositories` (pinning way):

```
@edge http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

Then run:

```
apk update
apk add apparmor@edge
```

Alpine Linux: [Repository pinning](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Repository_pinning)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the name of the package is `apparmor`, not `apparmor-utils`. That "utils" thing at the end of the package name is Ubuntu specific and on Alpine, `apparmor-utils` is a subpackage.

Try to install the entire apparmor thing with `apk update && apk add apparmor`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  I checked it on https://labs.play-with-docker.com. I started a container `docker run -it alpine` and then tried what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to install apparmor

```
apk update
apk add apparmor@edge  --force-broken-world
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that your approach reiterates mostly what was already described in the accepted answer, save for the `--force-broken-world` option. You may want to expand your answer to make the significance of that option clearer. If the difference is minor, you may want to submit an edit suggestion to the accepted answer instead.